# Vue Router hooks not triggered in component, using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

This has been puzzling me for a while. I have searched quite a bit, but still have no idea, why the route-hooks doesn’t work in component:

**1. The component is loaded from RouterView:**

```html
<router-view class="z1" :key="$route.name" />
```

**2. I have registered the hooks in `main.ts`, and also in `My.vue` -- BEFORE the class definition (to ensure the registration is right here):**

```js
Component.registerHooks([
    'beforeRouteEnter',
    'beforeRouteLeave',
    'beforeRouteUpdate',
]);
```

**3. The hook even works in my router config:**

```js
{
    path: '/my',
    name: 'my',
    component: My,
    // beforeEnter: (to: Route, from: Route, next: any): void => {
    //  console.log('It works!’);  // It works here!
    // }
},
```

**4. But it doesn’t work in my Component:**

```js
@Comp()
export default class My extends Vue {
    public beforeRouteEnter (to: Route, from: Route, next: any): void {
        debugger;       // not triggered!
        next((vm: Vue.Component) => {
            debugger;   // not triggered!
            next();
        });
    }
}
```

So could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

should be working:

```
@Comp({
  beforeRouteEnter (
    to: Route,
    from: Route,
    next: (to?: RawLocation | false | ((vm: V) => any) | void) => void
  ): void {
       next(vm => {});
  }
})
export default class My extends Vue {}
```

Comment: @Component decorator accepts an object with vue router hooks

Comment: I don't know why but the typing fixed it